# How to set up a shared team calendar in Sharepoint 365 that updates individual calendars when an event is cancelled or moved

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, outlook, sharepoint-calendar, team-sites

I have a team site and I've added the calendar.  I've synced the team site's calendar with my calendar in outlook.  I now have both calendars up side by side in my Outlook, which is great.  I am able to create and copy events on both calendars with no issues.  The problem I'm having is when the event is moved or cancelled.  If I cancel or delete an event on the team site, the version in my personal calendar does not show as canceled or deleted.  If I move the event on my team site, the item does not move on my personal calendar and vice versa.  How do I make this work?